# Multiple Array Assignment Depending on Variable

Tags: java

I'm new to Java..
Say if a user inputs a int, A.

```
int [] = arraylist [A]  // I created a variable with A values
```

How can I allow my user to input a value for each array value?

I thought by implementing an if/while statement, by looping the program until all values are assigned which could be the condition? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Yeah, you are on right path. Try it out. Come up with some code, and show us. BTW, your array creation is not correct. You haven't given any varaible name.

Comment: Take a look at the `length` property of your array.

Comment: The syntax to declare an int array looks like this: `int[] arrayName = new int[n];` You can replace _arrayName_ with any name you like.

Answer (score 0):

It seams you are mistaking Arrays with ArrayLists.

Here's a nice tutorial on arrays:

http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-arrays.html

And here are some examples with ArrayList.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html

In short, an array is a basic memory structure where as an ArrayList is an Object from the Java Libraries.

Comment: What makes you think he's confusing arrays and ArrayLists?  He defines the size of the array when he declares it... he just wants to know how to populate it.  An array works fine in this scenario. EDIT: Oh... I see his edit now.  You may be right!